# Paypal Payflow API Java SSL Certificate

Tags: paypal

I'm using Paypal Payflow API to perform AUTH, Capture, Void, and Credit Transaction. I was able to perform the above transactions with Java successfully. However, I would like how to set up the Certificate in the Java keystore for Paypal. Is this necessary? Please note that other systems in our environment calls my code via Socket to perform transactions and my code is responsbile for accessing the Paypal. There is no web server/web container involved to configure the SSL.

The credit card numbers that I receive from other systems are encrypted and I'm decrypting it in my end before sending it to the PayPal. I believe these card numbers are transferred in clear text format from my code to the Paypal. How should I securely send the credit card numbers to Paypal?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's API endpoint(s) use SSL(v3), so no, you do not need to further encrypt it for transport.
Though it is advisable to apply [SSL pinning](http://www.threatgeek.com/2011/11/ssl-pinning-in-the-enterprise-part-1.html) to ensure you do not allow any other CA's other than the one who signed PayPal certificate.